# Display an image as part of a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a race  using javascript. I have two images that start on the left side. Once the user clicks go, they move at random intervals towards the right side. Once they reach the right side they stop. I need to display an image indicating which image reached the end first. I have the race portion of it working but when they reach the end, the winners image never shows up. Thanks for any help?

```
function move_img(str) 
{
    var x=document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
    x= x +100;
    document.getElementById('i1').style.top= x + "px";
}

function playerOne()
{
    var step = Math.random();
    var y1=document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
    var x1=document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
    if(x1 < 500 ){x1= x1 +step;
        document.getElementById('i1').style.left= x1 + "px";
    }

    return x1;
}

function playerTwo()
{
    var step = Math.random();
    var y2=document.getElementById('i2').offsetTop;
    var x2=document.getElementById('i2').offsetLeft;
    if(x2 < 500 ){x2= x2 +step;
        document.getElementById('i2').style.left= x2 + "px";
    }

    return x2;
}

function timer()
{
    var x1 = 0;
    var x2 = 0;

    if ( (x1 < 500 && x2 < 500))
    {
        playerOne();
        playerTwo();
        var x=document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
        var y=document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop;
        my_time=setTimeout('timer()',10);
        x1 = document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
    } else if ( (x1 == 500 && x2 < 500))
    {
        function winnerPlayerOne()
        {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = "/images/winner_ford.png";
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }

    } else {
        function winnerPlayerTwo()
        {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "/images/winner_meis.png";
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could always make the img always present but hidden, then change it to display when conditions are met

Comment: I hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/avc30hdf/27/

Comment: You are defining winnerPlayerOne() and winnerPlayerTwo() functions but *not calling them.* Although trying to define functions conditionally like that is a bad idea. Probably better to have an addImage() function defined at the top and then from within your if/else call it and pass it the url of the image to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested who finds this later, this is how I got it working:

HTML:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>The Race for an A!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="race.css"> 
            <script type='text/JavaScript' src="race.js" language=javascript>
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>

            <h1 class = "amazing"> The Amazing Race For an A! </h1>

            <h1 class = "fordmeis"> Professor Ford Vs Michael Meis </h1>

            <div id="traffic-light">
            <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
            <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
            <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
            </div>

            <input type=button onClick="illuminateGreen();timer();" value='Go!' style="position: absolute; left: 545px; top:265px;">

            <img src=images/teacher.jpg id='i1' style="position:absolute; left: 25; top: 325; z-index:2;" width ="100" >
                <br><br><br><br>
            <img src=images/meis.png id='i2' style="position:absolute; left: 25; top: 500; z-index:2;" width ="100">
            <img src=images/road.jpg id='road' style="position:absolute; left: 30; top: 325; z-index:1;" height = "133" width ="1180">
            <img src=images/road.jpg id='road' style="position:absolute; left: 30; top: 500; z-index:1;" height = "133" width ="1180">
            <img src=images/winner_ford.png id='image1' style="position:absolute; left: 5; top: 0; z-index:3;" width ="100%" height = "100%" onclick="reset()">
                <br><br><br><br>
            <img src=images/winner_meis.png id='image2' style="position:absolute; left: 5; top: 0; z-index:3;" width ="100%" height = "100%" onclick="reset()">

            <script>
                illuminateRed()
                hideImage()
            </script>

        <div class="vertical-line" />

        </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
<!--

function hideImage() 
{
    document.getElementById("image1").src = "images/winner_ford.png";
    document.getElementById("image2").src = "images/winner_meis.png";

    document.getElementById("image1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("image2").style.visibility = "hidden";

}

function meis()
{
    document.getElementById("image2").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function ford()
{
    document.getElementById("image1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function timer()
{
    var x1 = 0;
    var x2 = 0;
    var step1 = Math.random();
    var step2 = Math.random();
    var x1=document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft;
    var x2=document.getElementById('i2').offsetLeft;

    if(x1 < 1100 && x2 < 1100)
    {
        x1 = x1 + step1;
        x2 = x2 + step2;

        document.getElementById('i1').style.left= x1 + "px";
        document.getElementById('i2').style.left= x2 + "px";

        setTimeout('timer()', 1);
    }else if ( x1 >= 1100 )
        {
            ford();
        }
        else if ( x2 >= 1100 )
        {
            meis()
        }
}

function illuminateRed()
    {
    clearLights();
    document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

function illuminateGreen() {
    clearLights();
    document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

function clearLights() {
    document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }

function reset()
{
    location.reload()
}

//-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your code.

The first one is that you assume a particular winner to land right on the 500 margin while increasing it's value by random numbers.

```
if ( (x1 == 500 && x2 < 500))
```

In the above condition, x1, the winner here, can well be beyond 500 according to your logic.

The second problem is, assuming your logic somehow reaches image creation part, that you create images and just add it to the body. You never say where these images should show up.

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "/images/winner_ford.png";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

There is a high chance the above code will create an image, but sneak under another absolutely-positioned element when added to the body.

Comment: It is definitely the second problem. First problem will mean that only second player is the winner, no matter what (thanks to last else statement). Not providing any position whatsoever, no size either is the problem.

Comment: The second problem may occur in the future, after the OP fixes the code so that the image creation code actually runs - currently those lines are inside functions that aren't called.

Comment: Ya, the last else statement somehow catches the image creation code. But this even happens when both x1 == 500 and x2 == 500 or both are more than 500. But only one image is created in both these cases which might mislead the OP for his results. Thats why I raised this point.

Comment: So I defined three functions at the top showImage, winnerPlayerOne and winnerPlayertwo at the top and then conditionally called those functions in my if else within the timer function. I'm still not getting it to show up. I have added alignment and size attributes as well. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: when I put it in there, the stoplight and the movement stopped working... but it works when i open it in a browser. I've never used fiddle before so I'm sure I put it in wrong.

Comment: I tried your fiddle. But nothing works there. Please read some articles about fiddle and produce your error there.